# Error 429 in IIS and 64 Bit Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I am trying to deploy a 32bit ASP web app on Server 2008 and IIS 7.

I have another server where the app is running fine, but on this server, every time I load the ASP Page that calls one of my DLL's I get Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object in *DLL*.

I have tried all of the fixes I have found online for this problem, including the following:
Enable 32Bit applications on the app pool.
ReRegister the DLL's (using RegSvr32) from the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 Folder

When I run the SysInternals Process Monitor and compare the results, the main thing I notice is that on the machine that runs properly, when I load the page there is an even mix of activity between the dllhost.exe prcoess and w3wp.exe process.

In the server that fails I see calls to the registry that aren't getting made in the successful server, including a few that I don't have any idea what they are: 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VBA\Monitors
HKCR\Wow6432Node\Interface{6F255EB7-E73A-4579-B0EC-045FBC00992D}\InterfaceHelperDisableTypeLib
HKCR\Wow6432Node\Interface{6F255EB7-E73A-4579-B0EC-045FBC00992D}\InterfaceHelperDisableAll
HKCR\Wow6432Node\Interface{6F255EB7-E73A-4579-B0EC-045FBC00992D}\InterfaceHelperUser

And all of these calls are made using the dllhost.exe process. The w3wp.exe process doesn't come in again until it's time to present the error page.

I should mention that these are two brand new servers. We have not been able to identify the configuration difference between them.

Also worth mentioning, even though I am expected to support this app, I have no access to source code, and cannot execute the source in any kind of debug mode with break points or anything like that.

I strongly suspect that there is some sort of configuration error with the way we are trying to run this 32bit code on a 64bit server, but I am out of ideas for how to prove it, or leads on how to fix it.

Thanks,
Bill

UPDATE:
The problem turned out to be a .tlb file that needed to be regenerated. Some of the few people in my company that do C# development and are allowed to look at source code found pretty quickly that one of the DLL's that runs the app had a method available to do it. They whipped up a VB script that called it to generate the file and everything was up and running again.

I don't know enough about Windows development to know what a .tlb is or why that worked but the moral of the story is if you have a 32bit web app that won't run on a 64bit (maybe any server?) Windows server because of error 429, take a good look at your .tlb file. Just don't ask me what you should be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you have enabled IIS to run 32bit applications?

On you application pool, right-click and choose "Advanced Settings"

Then under General ensure "Enable 32-bit Applications is "True"

Typically this is set to "False" by default.

This also worked for me http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177394

[image]

Comment: Yes I did. In fact I double checked it just before posting this to make sure I wasn't missing anything quite that simple.